# How to find the first not null column name with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have telephone bills for all the month of the year. Here is the structure of the table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sct_conso_2015` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `January` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `February` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `March` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `April` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `May` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `June` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `July` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `August` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `September` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `October` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `November` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `December` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('pabx','gsm') NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `number` (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Each month when I receive bills for every number, I load them into the database, month after month.
On my application, I need to get the last month with amount not null. I have written this query but it seems wrong and I don't understand why :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN December IS NOT NULL THEN 'December'  
        WHEN November IS NOT NULL THEN 'November' 
        WHEN October IS NOT NULL THEN 'October' 
        WHEN September IS NOT NULL THEN 'September' 
        WHEN August IS NOT NULL THEN 'August'
        ELSE ''  
    END as 'Month' 
FROM sct_conso_2015 LIMIT 1
```

This is to get the last month with bills ready. In my case I am getting the month 'September', but October is already in the database. What is wrong in my query ?

Comment: Redesign your tables, one month per row.

Comment: Can you give me an overview as answer ?

Comment: create table phone_bills (id int, year int, month int, cost decimal(10,2) etc. Add some constraints too.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but it always gets the last non-null value, from the first row of your table. Assuming you need to know the last month with amount not null, of the last record entered, then you would have to make the following change to your SQL query:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN December IS NOT NULL THEN 'December'  
    WHEN November IS NOT NULL THEN 'November' 
    WHEN October IS NOT NULL THEN 'October' 
    WHEN September IS NOT NULL THEN 'September' 
    WHEN August IS NOT NULL THEN 'August'
    ELSE ''  
END as 'Month' 
FROM (SELECT * FROM sct_conso_2015 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) as LastRow 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL `COALESCE()` function returns the `first non-NULL` value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT COALESCE(December,November,October...) Month
FROM sct_conso_2015 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: In my case I want the name of the column that was not null, but coalesce returns the value of that row I guess